# TypeError: Function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, turtle-graphics

there is some problem I cant execute the function

in main.py from another file
it give's the error self argument missing

The code

from here I import the car Manger class
store it in a object called car and and use car.create() in the while loop
MAIN.PY

<

```
import time
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player
from car_manager import CarManager
# from scoreboard import Scoreboard

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

player = Player() 
car = CarManager

screen.listen()

screen.onkeypress(player.moveup,"w")
screen.onkeypress(player.moveup,"Up")

counter = 0
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()

    if counter % 6 == 0:
        car.create() # the error
    counter += 1
    

screen.exitonclick()
```

> 

**car manger.py**

<

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random
# COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
MOVE_INCREMENT = 10


class CarManager(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create()

    def create(self):
        self.shape("Square")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=2,stretch_len=1)
        self.penup()
        self.Y = random.randint(-250,250)
        self.goto(300,self.Y)
        self.setheading(180)

    def move(self):
        self.forward(STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE)
```

> 

Comment: `car = CarManager` should be `car = CarManager()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `car = CarManager`, which assigns the class `CarManager` itself to be the value of `car`, you wanted `car = CarManager()`, which creates an instance of type `CarManager` and assigns that to `car`. You then don't need to call `.create()` since `__init__()` already calls it.

Consider just putting that code in `__init__`, unless you want a factory method like this:

```
class CarManager(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("Square")
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=2,stretch_len=1)
        self.penup()
        self.Y = random.randint(-250,250)
        self.goto(300,self.Y)
        self.setheading(180)
   
    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        return cls()

    def move(self):
        self.forward(STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE)



car = CarManager.create()
```